# how to list resources over a vm on microsoft azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a old vm on microsoft azure, that I need to delete. There are a bunch of resources over that vm (vnet, public ip, disk, ...)

As I don't want to have unused resources, is it possibile to list all resources linked to another?

thank so much!
N.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing built-in in Azure to achieve this, kinda. One way of doing this (if you are not using shared virtual networks, backups, etc) is to put all the resources that logically relate to the vm in the same resource group and just delete the resource group.

an alternative would be to create a script to delete all the related resources along with the vm

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what looks like this script?

Comment: something like the blog post that was already linked: https://4sysops.com/archives/delete-an-azure-vm-with-objects-using-powershell/